# objects created using an array, not able to call it's method!! Why?

Tags: java

I created 2 source code files, **Shirt.java** and **ShirtTestArray.java**

The problem I am facing is that whenever I try to access the displayShirtInformation() method, I'm not able to do it.. and get an error **class,interface,or enum expected**

The 2 source files are given below--

**Shirt.java--**

```
public class Shirt {

  public int shirtID = 0; // Default ID for the shirt
  public String description = "-description required-"; // default

  // The color codes are R=Red, B=Blue, G=Green, U=Unset
  public char colorCode = 'U';
  public double price = 0.0; // Default price for all shirts
  public int quantityInStock = 0; // Default quantity for all shirts

  public Shirt() {
  }

  public Shirt(int ID, String d, char c, double p, int q) {
    shirtID = ID;
    description = d;
    colorCode = c;
    price = p;
    quantityInStock = q;
  }

  // This method displays the values for an item
  public void displayShirtInformation() {

    System.out.println("Shirt ID: " + shirtID);
    System.out.println("Shirt description:" + description);
    System.out.println("Color Code: " + colorCode);
    System.out.println("Shirt price: " + price);
    System.out.println("Quantity in stock: " + quantityInStock);

  } // end of display method
} // end of class
```

**ShirtTestArray.java --**

```
public void  ShirtTestArray{
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Shirt [] shirtArray={new Shirt (1,"blue",'b',76.67,4),new Shirt(2,"green",'g',98.79,1),
    new Shirt(3,"green",'g',34.78,90)};

    shirtArray[0].displayShirtInformation();
    shirtArray[1].displayShirtInformation();
    shirtArray[2].displayShirtInformation();

  }
}
```

Comment: In the interest of following OO best practices, please make your member variables private - that, or consider an `immutable` object.  You may also wish to change your 'color' `char` to an `enum`, to prevent data-entry errors (which your _own_ code possibly falls victim to - is the case important?).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second class should be declared as class, not void:

```
public class ShirtTestArray{
       ^
    public static void main(String [] args){
    Shirt [] shirtArray={new Shirt

(1,"blue",'b',76.67,4),new Shirt(2,"green",'g',98.79,1),
    new Shirt(3,"green",'g',34.78,90)};



       shirtArray[0].displayShirtInformation();
       shirtArray[1].displayShirtInformation();
       shirtArray[2].displayShirtInformation();

    }

}
```

Comment: nice catch, didn't see that one.

Answer (score 0):

You're giving ShirtTestArray a return definition, saying it should be a method, when it should be a class.

Replace 'void' with 'class' and you should be rolling.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error is `public void ShirtTestArray{` instead of `public class ShirtTestArray{`.
Cheers :)